# What does "shivering" means?

Tags: meaning

In this passage what does the meaning of Shivering?

> Did you ever get so angry that you start **shivering** and can't even show it to anyone, but sit here and update status thinking it might help.

Comment: Google Books has thousands of written instances of things like [*shivering with rage*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shivering+with+rage%22) and [*shaking with anger*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shaking+with+anger%22), and I'd guess most of them would be quite literal, not really metaphoric at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain you the situation by making you imagine another one. **Have you clenched your teeth so hard that your head starts to vibrate?** If not, try to do it right now. People do that when they are extremely angry and are out of words. That is what is meant by shivering here.

Comment: Yes I got it now.

Answer (score -1):

trembling, quaking............

Comment: You'd be at least 10 times more likely to be ***quaking / trembling*** with ***fear*** than with ***anger / rage***, so I'm not sure these are the ideal terms to match with OP's cited usage.

Comment: Just listed them to give a rough idea of what the author was implying. Never did I say "these words may be used interchangeably"